Scaling up a Motor
If I take a DDR motor (Direct Drive motor like a washing machine 3 phase DC motor) and make a larger version of it so the diameter is 2x and the magnets and coils are correspondingly wider for the larger circumference but everything else remains the same (same no of coils, same turns and current going through each, same no of magnets and strength/thickness etc of each), is my torque going to be 2x?


@liaifat85 but torque is a function of radius, not radius squared?
